# GitLab production deployment - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: laravel, docker, deployment, gitlab, laravel-envoy

This is the first time I’m deploying a Laravel application by using GitLab, or Docker images, and I might just have some confusion regarding the process.

I followed this guide: [laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/), and everything seems to work untill deployment begins.
I can see that my files were actually uploaded to the server, but the deployment job always ends with error.

Target production server is simple shared hosting, and I have ssh-connection to there (sudo doesn’t seem to work though, so I can't for example edit the actual ssh configs).

I’m a bit confused about the `@server` directive of `Envoy.blade.php`, and have already tried different credentials there. But now I’m pretty sure I should have my `ssh_username@production_ip` there, yet the GitLab deployment job ends with this error:

```
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ ~/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy run deploy --commit="$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
[ssh_username@production_ip]: Cloning repository
[ssh_username@production_ip]: Cloning into 'app/releases/20200522043301'...
[ssh_username@production_ip]: Permission denied (publickey).
[ssh_username@production_ip]: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ssh_username@production_ip]: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ssh_username@production_ip]: and the repository exists.
[✗] This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers.
```

And now I’m not sure which permissions I’m lacking, because the main app files already got uploaded to `app_dir`. Does this mean it for some reason can’t get the release files from GitLab or something else?

Or might I have something wrong in my Docker image at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huhuh, I finally found the issue. I had to manually create `.ssh/config` file with the following content:

```
Host gitlab.com
User git
Hostname gitlab.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/deploy_key
TCPKeepAlive yes
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

And now deployment process is finally able to upload the release versions too!